# Werkzeug raises BrokenFilesystemWarning

Tags: python, unix, encoding, utf-8, flask

I get the following error when I send form data to my Flask app.  It says it will use the UTF-8 encoding, but the locale is already UTF-8.  What does this error mean?

```
/home/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/filesystem.py:63:
BrokenFilesystemWarning: Detected a misconfigured UNIX filesystem:
Will use UTF-8 as filesystem encoding instead of 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
```

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not a critical error, just a warning that Werkzeug couldn't detect a good locale and so is using `UTF-8` instead.  This guess is probably correct.

See [this Arch Linux wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale) for how to set up the locale correctly.  It mentions that Python may see the `ANSI_X3.4-1968` encoding even if the locale is properly configured, if you are running from certain environments such as Vim.

> When executing `:!python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"` in ViM, the output may be `ANSI_X3.4-1968`, even if the locale is set correctly everyhere. Set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to `utf-8` to remedy the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error too. After digging the code, I saw that this error is harmless and just a warning in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/filesystem.py`:

```
        warnings.warn(
            'Detected a misconfigured UNIX filesystem: Will use UTF-8 as '
            'filesystem encoding instead of {0!r}'.format(rv),
            BrokenFilesystemWarning)
```

So, I would not worry about this warning.

Comment: I've solved it. In my case I was running my script in a Docker container with a different Python version (3.6.9) that I used to develop and test it (3.7.5). So, now I've installed the same version into the container and don't get this error anymore. I hope this would be useful for others.