# convert ampersand character to utf 8

Tags: ios, swift, encoding

I send post request with data to my server:

```
var syncData = "data=Hello&World"
let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!, cachePolicy:  NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: NSTimeInterval(60))

urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
urlRequest.HTTPBody = syncData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

But problem that server can't decode `&(ampersand)` character. On server i get only word "Hello". And it is not the server issue. because i tried to sent this string with java and python and curl.
All works good.

I tried this:
[NSXMLParser problem with "&"(Ampersand) character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291534/nsxmlparser-problem-with-ampersand-character)

but it doesn't help... Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly happens?

Comment: server decode only part of string. For example if string was Hello&World, in post data server decode only hello...

Comment: This is what happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515331/werkzeug-raises-brokenfilesystemwarning

Comment: Your data is not properly encoded, `&` has a special meaning and needs to be escaped so your string should be `data=Hello%26World` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Musa said. Solution will be:

```
let customAllowedSet =  NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"=\"#%/<>?@\\^`{|}&").invertedSet
    syncData = syncData.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(customAllowedSet)!

    urlRequest.HTTPBody = syncData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var sync = syncData.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&", withString: " ")
urlRequest.HTTPBody = sync.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

place the sync variable under the syncData variable and replace your urlRequest with the one above using the new sync variable

Comment: yes, replace is the solution, but it is very bad solution :(  I need some unique character to replace. Because i haven't only urls, i have large texts too, that can contains ampersands and spaces